# Starting my website in Debug not working after Azure Key Vault Configuration ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-keyvault, azure-authentication

I have a full functioning website. Yesterday I have bound my secrets using Azure Key Vault Service.
In my secrets I'm only storing the SendGridKey and EmailKey.
The following dependencies have been added in my `csproj` file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets" Version="1.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.1.0" />
```

My `Program.cs` file has been automatically updated as follows:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                {
                    var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyKeyVault"));
                    config.AddAzureKeyVault(
                    keyVaultEndpoint,
                    new DefaultAzureCredential());
                })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();

                });
```

Publishing the website in Azure still works perfectly, but I'm not more able to start my website in Debug modus.

I'm getting the following error:

```
An error occurred while starting the application.
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString')
System.Uri..ctor(string uriString)
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString')
```

The problem is:

```
var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyKeyVault"));
```

because `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyKeyVault")` is returning NULL

My Startup file is:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        var options = new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRedirectToWwwPermanent()
            .AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent();

        app.UseRewriter(options);

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

**Update**

I have a similar project with the following code block:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                var keyVaultEndpoint = GetKeyVaultEndpoint();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
                {
                    var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                    var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
                        new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
                            azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
                    config.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
                }
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
    private static string GetKeyVaultEndpoint() => "https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/";
```

I've used the following packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" Version="3.0.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" Version="1.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault" Version="3.1.8" />
<PackageReference Include="SendGrid" Version="9.21.0" />
```

Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication has been deprecated and the above code works no longer in my new project. It works indeed in my old one.

Comment: Is the MyKeyVault variable actually set? Typically, when I trubleshoot these kind of problems I add a simple loop at the start of the app, that sends all the environment variables to the log, to verify what is actually set.

Comment: Hi Tore. No I did not set this variable a second time. My secrets values are contained in the secrets.json file. I assumed that in Debug modus things were going on as before setting Azure Key Vaults, but I'm probably wrong. It would be great if you could share the code snippet you were talking about (to check all the environment variables). The only way I've found as a quick and dirty solution is to comment out the section 'ConfigureAppConfiguration' and it works again also while debugging!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this few lines of code, it works again both in development and production:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                {
                    if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
                    {

                        // Do simply nothing
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyKeyVault"));
                        config.AddAzureKeyVault(
                        keyVaultEndpoint,
                        new DefaultAzureCredential());
                    }
                                           
                })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

In development, the secrets are retrieved from `secrets.json`, in production from Azure KeyVault.

Answer (score 0):

To debug Environment variable issues, it can be useful debug trick to dump all the variables that the application can see to the console or log.

Using code like:

```
    foreach(DictionaryEntry env in Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(env.Key + ":" + env.Value);
    }
```

Be aware of the security issues doing this, as secrets might end up in the wrong place. The alternative is to just print out the variables names or just the first few characters of each variable, like

```
Console.WriteLine(env.Key + " : " + env.Value.ToString().Substring(0,5));
```

Comment: Hi Tore, thanks a lot for the snippet. I've added it in my code and, indeed the MyKeyVault variable is not set. I've added it in the launchSettings.json file under the section "profiles" "environmentVariables". The snippet recognizes it. The expected value is an URI, that poits to the KeyVault. I'm getting now another error. MsalServiceException: AADSTS9002332. (Azure Key Vault) is configured for use by Azure Active Directory users only. Additionally I think a bout security issues exposing the Azure KeyVault URI as env variable.

Comment: In the Properties folder of my project there are 3 files containing service dependencies settings: serviceDependencies.json, serviceDependencies.local.json.user and serviceDependencies.MyWebsiteName - Erb Deploy.json.user  In the serviceDependencies.json file I can see a "dependencies" block containing the reference to MyKeyVault as "connectionId":"MyKeyVault". In the serviceDependencies.local.json.user file there are references to my Azure KeyVault such as ResourceGroupName, SubscriptionId and so on

Comment: I usually put all the config in Azure Key Vault and just add my Azure Key Vault credentials as input environment variables. How is the app hosted in Azure?

Comment: Yes it is hosted in Azure. But I did not add any environmental variables like Azure Key Vault credentials.How should this work?

Comment: How do you host it in Azure? you have many alternative options in Azure.

Comment: I have my resource group, my app service plan (B1), my app, my SSL app certificate and my Key Vault inside it. In the KeyVault settings I have Vault access policy

Comment: in AppServices, you can under Settings -> Configuration set the various Application settings, that will end up as environment variables inside the app.

Comment: This setting item is already present and contains the URI of the KeyVault. I think that the problem is that the access to this settings item is somehow blocked. Only Azure AD users can acces this. But this is somehow strange because I've set it properly in the Access Policies

Comment: Have you given the App registration in Azure AD both GET and LIST access in Azure Key Vault? The app needs to be able to both LIST all secrets and then GET them one by one.

Comment: Yes, both GET and LIST are there